# Loop though properties of an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have the set of data.how would you loop through this data using a for loop in JavaScript?

```
    var model = ({
        "DettolRadiance":
            {
                "Values": [{ "GRPsValue": 66, "MonthOfSale": "Jan" },
                  { "GRPsValue": 100, "MonthOfSale": "Feb" },
                  { "GRPsValue": 250, "MonthOfSale": "March" },
                  { "GRPsValue": 100, "MonthOfSale": "April" }],
                "Key": "DettolRadiance"
            },
        "DettolSkinCare":
            {
                 "Values": [{ "GRPsValue": 487, "MonthOfSale": "Jan" },
                        { "GRPsValue": 450, "MonthOfSale": "Feb" },
                        { "GRPsValue": 300, "MonthOfSale": "March" },
                        { "GRPsValue": 400, "MonthOfSale": "April" }],
                 "Key": "DettolSkinCare"
            },
        "DettolToiletSoaps":
                    {
                 "Values": [{ "GRPsValue": 64, "MonthOfSale": "Feb" },
                            { "GRPsValue": 0,  "MonthOfSale": "Jan" },
                            { "GRPsValue": 70, "MonthOfSale": "March" },
                            { "GRPsValue": 150, "MonthOfSale": "April" }],
                 "Key": "DettolToiletSoaps"
             }
    });
```

Here is the code which I have tried.

```
      var DataSet = [];

           for (var i = 0; i < model[0].DettolRadiance.Values.length; i++) {

            DataSet.push({ 'x': model[0].DettolRadiance.Values[i].MonthOfSale, 'y': model[0].DettolRadiance.Values[i].GRPsValue });

        }

            for (var i = 0; i < model[0].DettolSkinCare.Values.length; i++) {

            DataSet.push({ 'x': model[0].DettolSkinCare.Values[i].MonthOfSale, 'y': model[0].DettolSkinCare.Values[i].GRPsValue });
        }


             for (var i = 0; i < model[0].DettolToiletSoaps.Values.length; i++) {

            DataSet.push({ 'x': model[0].DettolToiletSoaps.Values[i].MonthOfSale, 'y': model[0].DettolToiletSoaps.Values[i].GRPsValue });
        }
```

But I am able to retrieve only Values.I want  to retrieve values based on 3 keys.Those are DettolRadiance,DettolSkinCare,DettolToiletSoaps.So Each key should have 4 respective values.I think I need to add another for loop.But I am not getting the exact syntax.Can anyone please help..

Comment: `model` is an object literal - not an array. I edited the title to reflect this.

Comment: Also you don´t want to pass it to $ (which is often jQuery).

Comment: Thanks @  papirtiger for making the things very clear.

Comment: why model[0].DettolSkinCare and not model.DettolSkinCare as per your object model is not array

Comment: Read a real basic tutorial on JavaScript objects, arrays, and loops.

Answer (score 0):

i think you code should be

```js
  var model = ({
        "DettolRadiance":
            {
                "Values": [{ "GRPsValue": 66, "MonthOfSale": "Jan" },
                  { "GRPsValue": 100, "MonthOfSale": "Feb" },
                  { "GRPsValue": 250, "MonthOfSale": "March" },
                  { "GRPsValue": 100, "MonthOfSale": "April" }],
                "Key": "DettolRadiance"
            },
        "DettolSkinCare":
            {
                 "Values": [{ "GRPsValue": 487, "MonthOfSale": "Jan" },
                        { "GRPsValue": 450, "MonthOfSale": "Feb" },
                        { "GRPsValue": 300, "MonthOfSale": "March" },
                        { "GRPsValue": 400, "MonthOfSale": "April" }],
                 "Key": "DettolSkinCare"
            },
        "DettolToiletSoaps":
                    {
                 "Values": [{ "GRPsValue": 64, "MonthOfSale": "Feb" },
                            { "GRPsValue": 0,  "MonthOfSale": "Jan" },
                            { "GRPsValue": 70, "MonthOfSale": "March" },
                            { "GRPsValue": 150, "MonthOfSale": "April" }],
                 "Key": "DettolToiletSoaps"
             }
    });

var DataSet = [];

           for (var i = 0; i < model.DettolRadiance.Values.length; i++) {
            DataSet.push({ 'x': model.DettolRadiance.Values[i].MonthOfSale, 'y': model.DettolRadiance.Values[i].GRPsValue });

        }

            for (var i = 0; i < model.DettolSkinCare.Values.length; i++) {

            DataSet.push({ 'x': model.DettolSkinCare.Values[i].MonthOfSale, 'y': model.DettolSkinCare.Values[i].GRPsValue });
        }


             for (var i = 0; i < model.DettolToiletSoaps.Values.length; i++) {

            DataSet.push({ 'x': model.DettolToiletSoaps.Values[i].MonthOfSale, 'y': model.DettolToiletSoaps.Values[i].GRPsValue });
        }
```

Comment: @rjdmello.When I try model.DettolSkinCare in console it says  undefined.If I give model[0].DettolSkinCare I get the data in console like this Object {Values: Array[4], Key: "DettolSkinCare "}

Answer (score -1):

I have written two functions which allow you to iterate over every individual member of an array/object or a combination of object and array (like yours).

First I have written a function to iterate over every individual member of an `array/object`. But this function also uses another function to check whether the object is `object object` or is `object array`, since we should slightly use different techniques for the two types.

```
function _recursive(obj, callback)
{
  var len;
  var objectKeys;
  var i  = 0;
  if(isArrayOrObject(obj) === 'array') 
  {
     len = obj.length; 
     iterator = i;
  }
  else if(isArrayOrObject(obj) === 'object') 
  {
     len = Object.keys(obj).length;

     objectKeys = Object.keys(obj);
  }

   for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
   {
       var currentElement;

       if(isArrayOrObject(obj) === 'array') 
       {
         currentElement = obj[i];
       }
       else if(isArrayOrObject(obj) === 'object') 
       {
         currentElement = obj[objectKeys[i]];
       }

       callback(currentElement);

       if(isArrayOrObject(currentElement) !== false)
       {         
             _recursive(currentElement, function(element){
                    callback(element);
              }); 
           }
       }
    }
```

This function checks the type of the object and returns false if neither are true.

```
function isArrayOrObject(inp)
{ 
  if(typeof inp !== 'object') return false;  
  if( Object.prototype.toString.call( inp ) === '[object Array]' ) 
    {
        return "array";
    } 
    else 
    {
      return "object"; 
    }

}
```

And here is how we call it. We pass a callback to our function to be applied to each individual member of the array.

```
_recursive(model, function(element){

    if(typeof element !== 'object')
    {
        console.log(element); 
    }
});
```

This loops through the object to the deepest root.

Comment: ...I am able to iterate the loop through my code.I can access each and every element also.My doubt is how can I use nested for loop so that I can get corresponding  key along with values. I am able to retrieve all the values and keys.But I want to know  where should I write the code to retrieve keys so that I get corresponding values for a particular key

Comment: @papirtiger way overcomplicated? kiddin' me? when I have made everything available through a function ? The rest are a description of the function...

Comment: No, I´m not - OP asked how to loop through the properties of a object with a given structure. Not for a function that will recursively loop over any array / object - functions which already exist in jQuery/Underscore/LoDash `.each` and `.map`.

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through object properities with [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

```
for (var prop in obj) {
  if( obj.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
    console.log("o." + prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
  } 
}
```

`hasOwnProperty` ensures that it is a "real" property and that we don't get tripped up if somebody has been monkying with `Object.prototype`.

To get an array with the collected `MonthOfSale` and `GRPsValue` of each product you would use `for..in` with an inner loop on `Values`.

```
function proccessData(data){
    var result = [];

    for (var prop in data) {
        if( data.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
            (function(product){
                var val, i, len = product.Values.length;
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
                    val = product.Values[i];
                    result.push({
                        x: val['MonthOfSale'],
                        y: val['GRPsValue']
                    });
                }
            }(data[prop]));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/maxcal/9uoqm6f8/3/

**PS: (added)**

When creating a object with literal notation don't wrap it in parens:

```
var model = {}; // good
var model = ({}); // bad, is there something missing here?
```

Although the result is the same it is confusing since it looks like you may have intended to pass the literal to a function.

**EDIT.** This will do the same as your accepted answer.

```
var data_set = [];

for (var prop in model) {
  if( model.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
     data_set.push({ values: model[prop].Values, key: model[prop].Key })
  } 
}
```

Comment: .I am able to iterate the loop through my code.I can access each and every element also.My doubt is how can I use nested for loop so that I can get corresponding key along with values. I am able to retrieve all the values and keys.But I want to know where should I write the code to retrieve keys so that I get corresponding values for a particular key –@papirtiger

Comment: Thats not what your original question says at all. It would have quite a lot easier if you wrote the desired result since you are using the word 'key' in a really confusing way. Key is usually used to describe a the name of property of an object (the left hand side) - when you are talking about the value of property (the right hand side) which you call "Key".